# Forward k3s traffic to host machine

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, k3s, traefik-ingress

Is it possible to make the k3s ingress route a certain path to a certain IP or port of a service which is not running inside the Kubernetes, but on same physical machine?

**My use-case**

Using single node k3s setup.

I have a special server running on the same host that the k3s is running on.
I'd like to expose it as an HTTP endpoint in the ingress.

e.g:

```
foo.example.com --> k3s ingress --> 127.0.0.1:99 (port on k3s machine)
```

or

```
foo.example.com --> k3s ingress --> 192.168.1.7:99 (something in the local network)
```

Is something like this possible or should there be some reverse proxy before the k3s server?

Comment: any update on this ? did you tried service type ? feel free to update the status of question if below answers you question.

Comment: @HarshManvar Sorry, got pulled into work vortex. Will try to check your example out ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: no worries sir, anytime feel free do let me know if that not works.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to make the k3s ingress route a certain path to a
> certain IP or port of a service which is not running inside the
> Kubernetes, but on same physical machine?

Yes you can do it with the **[ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname)** service.

You define one **service** and it points to specific physical **IP** outside of the cluster.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.database.example.com//192.168.4.5
```

Further you can use this **service** as normal service of Kubernetes but the request will get forwarded to **external** service.